# jQuery plugin SimpleModal body onclick close not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm having problems getting the SimpleModal jQuery plugin to close when the body is clicked. So far, only the 'X' button works to close it with:

```
$('a.modalCloseImg').hide();
```

Here is my code for launching the modalbox. Note that #login-link is the link that opens the box and #login-form is the hidden modal box.

```
// launch modal box
$("#login-link").click(function(){
    $("#login-form").modal();
});
```

I've tried adding

```
$("#login-form").modal(overlayClose:true);
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. (FYI that parameter is per the documentation of the SimpleModal box as seen [here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try launching the modal box with an additional parameter, like this:

```
// launch modal box
$("#login-link").click(function(){
    $("#login-form").modal({ overlayClose: true });
});
```

you forgot additional `{}`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to put this? Between `$("#login-link").click(function(){ });`? Cause if so, I tried that, and it prevented the modal from opening.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that earlier, but it isn't working for some weird reason.                                                            EDIT: Actually, nevermind. I updated the SimpleModal plugin. I was using an old version. Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you sure you tried `({ overlayClose: true })` and not `(overlayClose:true)` as you mentioned in you question?